# Dynamic Activation Function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm working on a research project which involves replacing certain ReLu activations with polynomial activations. The code I inherited is using Keras with TensorFlow backend - something I have little experience with.

Essentially I'm building a vanilla ResNet graph and I need to gradually swap out a few ReLus with custom functions. In other words, my custom activation needs to do the following:

```
def activation(x)
    approx = .1992 + .5002*x + .1997*x**2
    relu = tf.nn.relu(x)
    diff = (TOTAL_EPOCHS - CURRENT_EPOCH) / TOTAL_EPOCHS
    return (1-diff)*approx + diff*relu
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to make the function dynamic via the current epoch using keras and model.fit. I have tried a few things, like defining a custom layer, passing a counter variable, and trying to use tensorflow's global step variable but have run into annoying bugs with each one of those attempts. I was wondering if there's a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking? It seems like this should be trivial but I just lack experience with the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`keras.callbacks.Callback`](https://keras.io/callbacks/) to make the function dynamic via the current epoch using keras and `model.fit`. Here's an example to make the return value of the activation function equal to current epoch. From the MSE value you can quickly see that current epoch participates in the calculation of activation function.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Activation,Input
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
import keras.backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class MonitorCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, CURRENT_EPOCH):
        self.parm = CURRENT_EPOCH
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        K.set_value(self.parm, epoch)

CURRENT_EPOCH = K.variable(0)
TOTAL_EPOCHS = 8
def custom_activation(x):
    return CURRENT_EPOCH

num_input = Input(shape=(1,))
get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})
output = Activation(custom_activation)(num_input)
model = Model(num_input,output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])

model.fit(x=[1],y=[2],epochs=TOTAL_EPOCHS,callbacks=[MonitorCallback(CURRENT_EPOCH)])

# print
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/8
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: 4.0000 - mean_squared_error: 4.0000
Epoch 2/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0000 - mean_squared_error: 1.0000
Epoch 3/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0000 - mean_squared_error: 1.0000
Epoch 5/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 4.0000 - mean_squared_error: 4.0000
Epoch 6/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 9.0000 - mean_squared_error: 9.0000
Epoch 7/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 16.0000 - mean_squared_error: 16.0000
Epoch 8/8
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 25.0000 - mean_squared_error: 25.0000
```

Please keep in mind that epoch counts from zero in `keras.callbacks.Callback`. You can try replacing `custom_activation` with your activation function.

Comment: It worked - thanks so much!! Saved me a lot of time :)